# How to add user entries with password field in LDAP over HTTPS?

Tags: tls, passwords, authentication, password-management, ldap

I am new to this kind of stuff (HTTPS etc.) and pretty much confused on how to go ahead with this.

An LDAP server (ApacheDS) at the back-end stores the user details. To add new users, the user creation form can be provided as web service over HTTPS.

As per this [mail chain](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/389-users/2012-August/014908.html), LDIF files should better have `userPassword` as plain text so that the LDAP server takes care of hashing.

Is it possible to get the `userPassword` as plain text, at the server-side, when the password is entered by an end user on client side with HTTPS being used ? Is it a good idea at all ?

Or should I leave it to the user to hash it in SSHA on client-side and give it to the server, which I would add in the LDIF file ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get the `userPassword` as plain text, at the server-side, when the password is entered by an end user on client side with HTTPS being used ?

Yes. HTTPS is HTTP over TLS.  TLS stands for Transport Level Security, and, as the name implies, encrypts the [transport layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer).  That is, it's only designed to protect the data during its transfer over the network.

Generally there will be a TLS terminator (or SSL terminator) at the edge of your infrastructure; this software (or occasionally, hardware) decrypts the TLS encryption and passes the unencrypted underlying HTTP request on to the application server.  So yes, this is possible, and common.